# Xcode takes so much time to open project

Tags: macos, mac, ios, xcode

When I try to open a project in Xcode it takes too much time to open.

Xcode stop responding and after a long time, it then opens.

I’m running a MacBook Pro 2017 16gb, i7. I was facing this issue in my old MacBook Pro 2015 8Gb, i5 and that was the main reason why I upgrade it. I made a backup from the old Mac to the new one, so I don’t know if it’s related but it’s still the same. Also, I tried creating a new user and moving all my folders there and it’s still the same. I don’t really know what else to do.

Edit.
I already tried deleting temp file folders and reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: I bet something's screwy with one of the .plist files inside the .xcodeproj

Comment: @Spiff I don’t think so, because even if it’s a new project I just create, it happens.

Comment: Are you running any other apps?

Comment: @jmh well, even if I restart my mac it happens, so I don't know if might be a background process.